# System.Text.Json without using ignore child property or not mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

if I have this classes

```
public class Emp
{
public int id{get;set;}
public string name{get;set;}
public contact cont {get;set}
public int contID{get;set;}
}
```

```
public class contact
{
public int id{get;set;}
public string value{get;set;}
public bool isValid{get;set;}
public contactType contyp {get;set}
public int contypID{get;set;}
}
```

```
public class contactType
{
public string name{get;set;}
public contactType contyp {get;set}
public Icollection<contact> conts {get;set}
}
```

JSON configuration option like this in my program :

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x => {    
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;   
});
```

then I call my API method:

```
public ActionResult GetEmployee()
        {
List<Core_Person> per = _dbcontext.Emps.Where(e=>e.id==1 || e.id ==2).Include(e=>e.cont.contyp).ToList();
            _context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            return Ok(per);
```

```
    }
```

Result:

```
per
 [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Name": "json",
            "cont": {
                    "id": 461,
                    "value": "01222516515",
                    "contypID": 2,
                    "isVaild": true,
                    "contyp": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "Name": "Mobile",
                        "conts": [
                            null,
                            {
                                "id": 462,
                                "value": "01286168168",
                                "contypID": 2,
                                "isVaild": true,
                                "contyp": null
                            }
                        ]
                     }
        },
{
            "id": 2,
            "Name": "Mick",
            "cont": {
                    "id": 462,
                    "value": "01286168168",
                    "contypID": 2,
                    "isVaild": true,
                    "contyp": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "Name": "Mobile",
                        "conts": [
                            null,
                            {
                                "id": 461,
                                "value": "01222516515",
                                "contypID": 2,
                                "isVaild": true,
                                "contyp": null
                            }
                        ]
                     }
        }
]
```

now I want to stop stars ** section to be serialized without using [JsonIgnore] attribute

```
"id": 1,
            "Name": "json",
            "cont": {
                    "id": 461,
                    "value": "01222516515",
                    "contypID": 2,
                    "isVaild": true,
                    "contyp": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "Name": "Mobile",
                        **"conts": [
                            null,
                            {
                                "id": 462,
                                "value": "01286168168",
                                "contypID": 2,
                                "isVaild": true,
                                "contyp": null
                            }
                        ]**
                     }
        },
```

to be like this :

```
"id": 1,
            "Name": "json",
            "cont": {
                    "id": 461,
                    "value": "01222516515",
                    "contypID": 2,
                    "isVaild": true,
                    "contyp": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "Name": "Mobile",
                        **"conts": null**
                     }
        },
```

Comment: To avoid complex configuration and side effects I suggest to use some DTOs to get the result and eventually use something like [Automapper](https://automapper.org/) to populate it, in this way you have a complete control of what you return to the client.  Don't serialize entities directly to get the response from an API.

Comment: The problem that the application I work on  ERP application its contain a lot of Entities maybe 1000 and more so; if I will use DTO concept it will be headache to create every Entity as a DTO  and remove unwanted probertites. because that I want to reuse the existing entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply a custom `JsonConverter` in json serialization options only when you need it.

This is an example based on your classes:

```cs
public class contactTypeConverter : JsonConverter<contactType> {
    public override contactType? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, contactType value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WriteString("name", value.name);
        writer.WriteNull("conts"); // or don't include it if you don't want 
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then use it in a way like this:

```cs
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions {
    ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonOptions.Converters.Add(new contactTypeConverter());
var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, jsonOptions);
```

You could refer to [converter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) or source code for [System.Text.Json](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src) to see some sample of current implementations of converters.

Comment: I think this answer is the nearest i will try it with some inhansment

Answer (score 0):

You can use EF Core's [Ignore Property](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method#:%7E:text=The%20Ignore%20method%20is%20used,Contacts%20%7B%20get%3B%20set%3B%20%7D) method.

In your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<contactType>().Ignore(c => c.conts);
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

**Update:**

You can manually set `conts` to `null` after reading data from the database, and do not perform this step where needed:

```
foreach (var item in per)
{
    item.cont.contyp.conts = null;
}
```

This approach can cause performance issues, but it works for your current situation.

Comment: Thanks for your response but i need this filed; but I want to not  serialize it when i need to